# How to snap an object using a specific vertex in Object Mode?

Tags: modeling, vertices, transforms, snapping

I can change the origin point to the vertex I want it to snap with, but i loose the old origin location.

In 3DSMax i could do this simply by hovering over the vertex i wanted to use as a pivot and moving it and it would automatically select the nearest vertex as a pivot to snap to the vertex of the other object.

Help I really want to switch to blender but i really hate to sacrifice these little quality of life things max has.

EDIT:
Ok so maybe my explanation is a bit confusing but i found a youtube video of someone doing it in 3ds Max at 1:49 time.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Aa7NVKK7N4
See how the guy just hover over a vertex and it lets him move the object by that vertex and then snaps it to the vertex of another object, that is what i want to do.

Comment: a little suggestion,COMMA is free!From the beginning of your title,I read almost one hundred words without take a breath,so I finally don't get even one word.To illustrate what you want clearly will do good to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, any insight on my problem though?

Comment: @CMZneu: you didn't understand NatureK. He wanted to say: Add a sketch with annotation or a screenshot so we can understand what you mean. So please press "edit" and improve your question - or your question will soon be closed.

Comment: @Chris There, i linked a youtube video where a guy does what i want but in 3ds Max... so is it possible to do in blender without having to change the objects origin?

Comment: I have been working on an add-on that does exactly that, it has not been battle tested, so feel free to try it and report issues if you find any: https://github.com/JulienHeijmans/quicksnap

Comment: @JulienH Thanks i look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't grab a specific vertex in object mode.
But you can use a parented empty.

<sup>Vertex Snapping > Closest. You can't choose which vertex snaps.</sup>
[image]

<sup>Using a parented empty. Choose wchich vertex to use.</sup>
[image]

Comment: Thanks that works, still it's not as easy as in 3ds max but at least there is a way, maybe somebody has made an addons or tool that makes it as easy as in max.

Comment: Hi :). Yeah, having smart snapping would be really nice. Perhaps one day.